# Push notifications not asking permission when user loads app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Hi I have just released my app update with push notifications added into it. I was worried that it would not work properly so I did a bunch of testing. First with just a development certificate and then a production certificate using adhoc. Both ended up working and I was pleased when the adhoc worked.

Anyways the update has been live for about 8 hours now and for some reason push isn't working. I checked with my friend and have realized that the user is not being asked whether he wants to accept push notifications from my app. Which means when the token gets sent to my server, its appearing as (null). I have no idea why this is happening. When he goes into device settings --> notifications ---> my app does not appear on any of the lists (receiving push notifications or not receiving).

This is the code in my delegate that should trigger the request:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
 (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

If anyone knows why this is happening, input would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After configuring your app for push notifications and generating your SSL certificates you must also generate new provisioning profiles.

The developer portal displays this message on the App ID configuration page:

> After you have generated your Client SSL certificate, create a new provisioning profile containing the App ID you wish to use for notifications.

If you did not update your App Store provisioning profile after setting up push the OS will not provide you with a push token.

If this is your problem you just need to generate a new App Store distribution profile and submit a recompiled version signed with that profile.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Heiberg. I used the one I have been using this whole time for updates (so the old one) but the App id used in that provisioning profile is set for production push. I guess this does not matter then? Thanks

Comment: That's your problem then. You need to generate a new one. The OS will look at your app and say "this app's provisioning profile is not enabled for push notifications... we'll return a null token to him".

Comment: Thank you so much... such a dumb mistake, should have payed more attention. Will accept

Answer (score 12):

We thought we were having this same issue but found out that the app was actually working correctly. The user is only prompted once even if they uninstall and reinstall the app.

We were testing it by uninstalling the app and then reinstalling. iOS would remember how we had responded previously on that device and would not prompt again leading us to think there was a problem.

We found the best way to test is with the simulator and doing a "Reset Content and Settings".

Comment: This is an excellent point, and exactly what I was seeing too. Apparently, you can reset the notifications dialog by leaving the app uninstalled for "a day".